# Can't dump file error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing an application with Rails 3.0.3.

I got "Can't dump file" error at the following code.

```
   if @post.update_attributes params[:post]
      redirect_to post_path(@post) #<= ERROR HERE
```

After googling, I added 2 lines to fix that.

```
   if @post.update_attributes params[:post]
      params[:post][:photos_attributes] = nil
      params[:post][:attachments_attributes] = nil
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
```

Now the error's gone. But I don't understand why the error occurred and how it's fixed. I use active_record for the session store and it caused the error because a file can't be stored in DB. But why does redirect_to try to store file in the session?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: +1 for wanting to know _why_ the error is gone! :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding: `ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.serializer = :json` to config/application.rb solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's in the `photo_attributes` and `attachment_attributes`. My guess is that they contain some sort of info on files and saving them is not working correctly.

Maybe you can post your `Post` model for us to see?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing attachment_attributes contains uploaded files.

Uploaded files are stored in params as ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile objects, and objects of this type are are not serialisable, hence the error.